# How to put a limit into the results filtered? In my sqlite model, flask

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I wanted to display a table indirectly molded by the user of my web app. Unfortunately i want to limit the number of rows that is pulled from the db model so it only displays the last 10 rows inserted, so it doesnt bug out the html of the rest of the application. Right now i am pulling every data inserted, how could i limit it?

Here is the db model code

```
class Dado(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
LocalidadeDB=db.Column(db.String(40),nullable= False)
MarcaDB=db.Column(db.String(40),nullable= False)
ModeloDB=db.Column(db.String(120),nullable= False)
AnoDB=db.Column(db.Integer,nullable= False)
QuilometragemDB=db.Column(db.Integer)
PrecoDB=db.Column(db.Integer,nullable= False)
CorDB=db.Column(db.String(20),nullable= False)
nome_id=db.Column(db.String(30),db.ForeignKey('UsuarioDB.NomeDaEmpresaDB'),nullable= False)

def __repr__(self):
    return f"User('{self.MarcaDB}', '{self.ModeloDB}')"
```

Here it is the route and the filtering function.

```
@app.route("/TerceiraJanela")
  def TerceiraJanela():
TabelaTitulo = ("Marca", "Modelo", "Ano", "Quilometragem" , "Preço" , "Cor" , "Local"  )

return render_template("TerceiraJanela.html", title = "TerceiraJanela", TabelaTitulo =TabelaTitulo,Query=Dado.query.filter_by(nome_id = current_user.NomeDaEmpresaDB).all())
```

And here is a pic of the table that can become ginarmous.

[image: Also bcs it is pretty]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `limit`
See https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.limit

The example below will return up to 10 records.

`Dado.query.filter_by(nome_id = current_user.NomeDaEmpresaDB).limit(10).all()`

Comment: This will return the first 10 rows, not the last 10 that is desired

Comment: So order by insertion time.

Comment: I have a column called id which is basically shows what was the last one , i think i could order through that but what would the command be to invert it ? like instead of going 1 to 10 going 10 to 1

Comment: Manage to do it look  at the size of that beast return render_template("TerceiraJanela.html", title = "TerceiraJanela", TabelaTitulo =TabelaTitulo,Query=Dado.query.filter_by(nome_id = current_user.NomeDaEmpresaDB).order_by(Dado.id.desc()).limit(10).all())

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1 I am sorry but I do not under your last comment. Did it work or not?

Answer (score 0):

Just slice the query result (using [-10:] at the end):

```
return render_template("TerceiraJanela.html", title = "TerceiraJanela", TabelaTitulo =TabelaTitulo,Query=Dado.query.filter_by(nome_id = current_user.NomeDaEmpresaDB).all()[-10:])
```

Comment: This will fetch ALL records but will keep only 10 of them. Not very efficient.

Comment: Indeed. If performance is an issue, it would be better to limit rows inside the query. It's fine for not large tables though